# Not able to navigate to return url from SXA login component

Tags: sxa, login

I have secured a Sitecore SXA page on role basis and able to redirect to login page (which is using SXA login component) upon direct access of the page 
[http://abc/registration/login?returnUrl=%2Fregistration%2Fmy-profile][1]. But not able to navigate to return url (http://abc/registration/my-profile) upon successful login and always getting redirected to home page instead.

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow this instruction? 
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/setting_up/use_a_custom_sxa_login_page

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak, I have followed the blog but no luck

Comment: It started working when I clear the DestinationUrl field in the Login metadata item (/sitecore/content/Test/Tenant/Site/Data/Security/Login)

Comment: @ManideepYechuri - if you have found a solution, please self answer here so that others can benefit in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It started working when I clear the DestinationUrl field in the Login metadata item (/sitecore/content/Test/Tenant/Site/Data/Security/Login)